# default in extjs combo-box

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

i am using extjs 3.4

Here is my code :

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
        var myPanel = new Ext.Panel({
            renderTo : document.body,
            height   : 500,
            width    : 1000,
            title    : 'Simple Panel',
            html     : 'This is my content',
            frame    : true,
            items: {
            layout: 'form',
            width: 200,
            labelAlign: 'top',
            style: 'margin-top: 5px;',
            items: {        
                xtype: 'combo',
                id: 'x',
                width: 115,
                listWidth: 115,
                fieldLabel: '<b>My combo</b>',
                labelStyle: 'font-size: 11px;',
                style: 'margin-left:20px',
                labelSeparator: '',
                forceSelection: true,
                value: 'A',     
                store: ['A', 'B', 'c'],                 
                autoSelect: true                    
            }
    }
        });

    });
```

I want to make 'A' as a default ... right now it is showing only 'A' in the combo box ... and 'B' and 'c' are missing(means both are missing from the list)

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining a store properly or telling the combo which fields to use from the store.

Try the code below

```
var myPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    height: 500,
    width: 1000,
    title: 'Simple Panel',
    html: 'This is my content',
    frame: true,
    items: {
        layout: 'form',
        width: 200,
        labelAlign: 'top',
        style: 'margin-top: 5px;',
        items: {
            xtype: 'combo',
            id: 'x',
            width: 115,
            listWidth: 115,
            fieldLabel: '<b>My combo</b>',
            labelStyle: 'font-size: 11px;',
            style: 'margin-left:20px',
            labelSeparator: '',
            forceSelection: true,
            typeAhead: true,
            triggerAction: 'all',
            lazyRender:true,
            mode: 'local',
            value: 'A',
            store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                id: 0,
                fields: [
                    'myId',
                    'displayText'
                ],
                data: [['A', 'A'], ['B', 'B'],  ['C', 'C']]
            }),
            valueField: 'myId',
            displayField: 'displayText',
            autoSelect: true
        }
    }
});
```

Key differences to note:

```
mode: 'local',
store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
            id: 0,
            fields: [
                'myId',
                'displayText'
            ],
            data: [['A', 'A'], ['B', 'B'],  ['C', 'C']]
        }),
        valueField: 'myId',
        displayField: 'displayText'
```

Reference: [ExtJs 3.4 Combo with Local Data](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox)

Answer (score 0):

Append `mode : 'local'` to combo config.

It's possible to use combobox with array instead of store (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox-cfg-store)